# Oracle: What does this expression "<>" mean in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

In oracle, it says to create a query that includes an employee column and a colleague column (works in the same department)

and I see part of the ff. query

```
WHERE e.employee_id <> c.employee_id
```

What does <> imply?

Comment: It means not equal to.  In other programming languages, you would write it as `!=`.

Comment: The documentation does cover this, although it is quite hard to find even when you know what you're looking for.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions002.htm#SQLRF52106

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means not equal to . It's the same as `!=` in C-like languages.

Answer (score 3):

<> (Not Equal To) Not equal to .   also != is same

> but <> is ISO Standard and
>
> !=  Not equal to (not ISO standard)